# Mismatched type Expection on @Query with security expression

Tags: spring, spring-data

I'm currently trying to use the @Query with the spring security expression to match any user that belongs to the same region/location as the logged in user.

I'm using the following code to achieve this this

```
@Override
@Query(value = "select u from User u where u.region in :#{principal.region}")
Page<User> findAll(Pageable var1);
```

My User table has the following association to region

```
@ManyToMany( mappedBy = "users")
private List<Region> region = new ArrayList<>();
```

My Region table has the following association to users

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinTable(name = "region_users", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "region_id", referencedColumnName= "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
)
private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
```

my custom principal object has the following region field

```
private List<Region> region;

public UserPrincipal(Long id, String username, String password,
                     Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities, Role role, List<Region> region) {
    this.id = id;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.authorities = authorities;
    this.role = role;
    this.region = region;
}
```

with the following get method

```
public List<Region> getRegion() { return this.region; }
```

When I make a request to the api end point that uses the overridden find all method I get the following exception

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [com.example.ReportTool.model.Region@18ab655a] did not match expected type [java.util.Collection (n/a)]

Can anyone help me with this issue? also if this question is too vague please let me know.

Comment: You need to specify principal as parameter. `Page<User> findAll(Pageable var1, UserPrincipal principal);`

Comment: I should have mentioned that i'm using Spring data rest and i'm overriding the Find all method of the PagingAndSortingRepository therefore i can't add User Principal to the method

Comment: Well, then you have to create new method such as
`@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM USERS u WHERE u.region in :#{principal.region}",
    countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM USERS WHERE u.region in :#{principal.region}",
    nativeQuery = true)`
Page<User> findAllByRegion(Pageable var1, UserPrincipal principal);

Comment: Maybe i'm miss understanding the answer, but i don't see how that would solve the problem, i need to use the overridden findall method of the PagingAndSortingRepository, if i create a new query that doesn't override the existing method then i would need to override the existing controller created by spring data rest and create my own mapping for the get request and then call the new query.